# is there a special name for a function that generates a binary tree

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-functions

[image]If you graph `t` vs `i` for `n = 7*11^i+1 (= 2^k*j + 2^t - 1)` with `t` being the number of trailing 1s in the binary representation, you will see an inverted binary tree. Is there any special significance to this?

Comment: Please show the graph, to clarify your question.

Comment: It's not exactly a binary tree and the upper left point should not have the left leg connecting to anything, but it gives the gist of what I mean.

Comment: This is just the consequence of parity considerations when multiplying. For the powers (repeated multiplication), every other will end in the same way, every 4 will end the same way, etc... Multiplying by something else changes where these endings start (e.g. the ending with the least 0s before 1 might occur for odd or even exponent) but the overall pattern is the same.